# YouTubePlayerView in a fragment

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a fragment that has a bunch of android views to play variety of media items - images, mp4 videos, pdfs.

I want to support `YouTubePlayerView` to support playing of youtube videos. I am aware of using YouTubePlayerFragment, but I want to place `YouTubePlayerView` within a normal fragment. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question this week. I only have 1 `Activity` in my app and everything else is fragments so I didn't want to do the doc'd approach of extending `YouTubeActivity` just to use the `YouTubePlayerView`.

Instead, if you continue reading the docs state a `YouTubeFragment contains a YouTubePlayer`. So I ended up treating the fragment like a view and explicitly put a `<fragment>` tag in `MyFragment`'s layout. During `onCreateView` of `MyFragment` the YouTubeFragment is instantiated for me then I can get references to the YouTubeFragment **AND** the YouTubePlayer.

From `MyFragment`'s `onCreateView` I call this helper `initYouTube()`. 
**Note**: What you really want is the `YouTubePlayer`, not the `YouTubePlayerView` and like many programming tasks there are about infinite ways to get the job done. I then retain references to the player and YT fragment for later use in `MyFragment`'s lifecycle.

```
private void initYouTube() {

    if (youTubePlayerFragment == null) {
        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentById(R.id.youtube_frag);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.api_key), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                Log.i("Detail","YouTube Player onInitializationSuccess");

                // Don't do full screen
                player.setFullscreen(false);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer = player;
                    cueVideoIfNeeded();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.i("Detail", "Failed: "+youTubeInitializationResult);
                if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                    youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getMainActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    callToast(youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

YouTubeFragment XML, nested in `MyFragment`'s layout XML.

```
<RelativeLayout>..../>

    <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_frag"
                    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
                    android:layout_below="@id/detail_animal_action_relative_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                />

    <TextView>...../>
```

Final product gives me something like this.
[image]

Comment: Can you also add your fragment layout xml file ?

Comment: There you go man, added. Hope fully this helps clear things up for you. Please mark as accepted if you agree.

Comment: Fragment within a fragment would work only if added dynamically.

Comment: Nested fragment done statically works fine for my needs, and is totally an option. Once in my layout I dont need to remove/replace it. If you are looking at doing that then I agree adding dynamically would be better. Good luck!